# Help vote on answers to good questions

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

Sometimes a question gets asked, someone takes the time to respond, but the answer never receives any votes.  Sometimes those answers can be quite good, and it would be nice to reward those answers with upvotes.

Would you like to help vote on these answers to older questions?  If so, I can suggest a way.  Run the following query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/cs/query/889195/search-for-question-with-positive-score-where-all-answers-have-zero-score

Then click on some of the links in the results (you can sort by question score first if you want), and take a look to see if the answers are good.  This looks for questions where the question score is > 0, where there is at least one answer, and where all answers have a score of 0 (which usually means the answer was never voted on; sometimes for good reason, but sometimes because a nice answer was overlooked).

My thanks to [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) for [this solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297930/160917)!

Comment: A nice side effect (let's say the main reason to act is to reward answerers) is that the platform will then consider the question answered, which is good for the statistic and because the infamous bump by Community won't happen anymore.

Comment: A related issue is that questions tend to get no votes.